# How many steps does this recurrence take to get to 2 (or 1)?

Tags: ds.algorithms, time-complexity

$T(2) = T(1) = 1$

$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{\log n}) + \Theta(1)$

Basically, I wanted to know how many steps before the recursion stops?

I tried various approaches, but am not getting anywhere. <strike>I know for sure that this is $O((\log \log n)^2)$, but I wanted a $\Theta$ bound (tighter bound).</strike> (this analysis is incorrect as shown in the comments below).

I've also run a simple program to compare $n, T(n)$, and $\log \log n$.

```
         n        T(n) log log n
             2,    1,    0
             4,    2,    1
             8,    3,    1
            16,    3,    2
            32,    4,    2
            64,    4,    2
           128,    5,    2
           256,    5,    3
           512,    5,    3
          1024,    5,    3
          2048,    6,    3
             .
             .
             .
     134217728,    9,    4
             .
             .
             .
 2199023255552,   12,    5
 4398046511104,   12,    5
 8796093022208,   12,    5
17592186044416,   13,    5
```

(This is not homework)

Comment: Assuming “O(1)” in the second formula is 1 and a floor function is missing around the fraction “n / log n”, I think that it is easy to prove a lower bound T(n) = Ω(log n / log log n), which contradicts the upper bound you claim in the question.  How did you prove the upper bound?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The trivial upper bound is incorrect. How did you prove the lower bound? (I am guessing that you just set k=log n and asked how many times to divide n by k to get 1?)

Comment: Yes, I obtained the lower bound that way.  (If you are asking how to turn that argument into a rigorous proof of the lower bound, one way to do so is by proving that T is monotonically increasing and using the mathematical induction.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is $T(n) = \Theta(\log n /\log\log n)$.  (I'm assuming the $O(1)$ term in the recurrence is really $\Theta(1)$, since otherwise $T(n)$ has no lower bound.)

As you and Tsuyoshi already observed, you can derive a lower bound by overestimating the denominator in the recursive argument.  Consider the function $L_k(n)$ defined by the recurrence
$$
L_k(n) = L_k\left(\frac{n}{\log k}\right) + \Theta(1).
$$
The solution $L_k(n) = \Theta(\log n / \log \log k)$ follows from standard methods.  An easy inductive argument implies that $T(n) \ge L_k(n)$ for any $k\ge n$.  Thus, setting $k=n^2$ (for example) immediately gives us $T(n) = \Omega(\log n/\log\log n)$.

For the upper bound, the symmetric trick is to *under*-estimate the denominator in the recursive argument.  Consider the function $U_k(n)$ defined by the recurrence
$$
U_k(n) = \begin{cases}
   U_k\left(\frac{n}{\log k}\right) + O(1) & \text{if } n \ge k, 
   \\
   T(n) & \text{otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$
An easy inductive argument implies that $T(n) \le U_k(n)$ for any $k\le n$.  Assuming inductively that $T(n)$ is a nondecreasing function of $n$, the solution
$$
   U_k(n)
   \le T(k) + O\left( \frac{\log(n/k)}{\log \log k} \right)
$$
follows from standard methods.  Setting $k=\sqrt{n}$ gives us the simpler(?) recurrence
$$
   T(n) \le T(\sqrt{n}) + O\left( \frac{\log n}{\log \log n} \right),
$$
which is easy to solve by standard methods.

I'll walk through that one, too.  Multiply both sides by $\lg\lg n$:
$$
  T(n)\lg\lg n
  ~\le~ T(\sqrt{n})\lg\lg n + O(\log n)
  ~=~ T(\sqrt{n})(\lg\lg\sqrt{n} + 1) + O(\log n).
$$
Setting $LT(n) = T(n)\lg\lg n$ gives us
$$
  LT(n) \le LT(\sqrt{n}) + T(\sqrt{n}) + O(\log n).
$$
Assuming inductively that $T(n) \le 10^{10^{100}}\lg n$ for large enough $n$, the recurrence simplifies further to $LT(n) \le LT(\sqrt{n}) + O(\log n)$.  This recurrence expands into a geometric series, implying the solution $LT(n) = O(\log n)$, which implies $T(n) = O(\log n / \log\log n)$.

Hey look, all our inductive assumptions worked out!

**Short version:** Logarithmic factors *usually* act like constants in recurrences, because they change so slowly.  The details are often grungy, but straightforward with a little practice.  (A glaring exception is the recurrence $T(n) = T(n/2) + \Theta(n/\log n)$, whose solution is  $T(n) = \Theta(n\log\log n)$.)

Comment: Super! I didn't understand one step along the way though - how to you get $U_k(n) \le T(k) + O(\log(n/k)\log \log k)$. I mean how do you get the 'k' in the denominator in the term $\log(n/k)$?

Comment: Starting with n, how many times do you have to divide by [whatever] until the result is less than k?